# How to Play decrypted file

Tags: asp.net, video, encryption, video-streaming

For video's to be copy protected , I thought of

Step-1) encrypting video files with key.

step-2)Decrypting a file OR  decrypt  in memory stream.

Step-3) Play decrypted file OR Play from Memory stream.

I have succesfully encrypted and decrypted a video file with key. But don't know how to play decrypted file(.dnc file).

Can somebody will please help me to play video file from decrypted (File or Memory Stream).

Code for Decryption

```
 private void Decryption(string filePath)
        {
            try
            {
                DateTime current = DateTime.Now;
                string encName = filePath + "data" + ".enc";
                RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();

                #region Seperate key and data
                byte[] alldata = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
                byte[] getencryptedkey = new byte[128];
                byte[] data = new byte[alldata.Length - 128];
                for (int i = 0; i < alldata.Length - 128; i++)
                { data[i] = alldata[i]; }
                for (int i = alldata.Length - 128, j = 0; i < alldata.Length; i++, j++)
                { getencryptedkey[j] = alldata[i]; }
                using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(File.Create(encName)))
                {
                    bw.Write(data);
                    bw.Close();
                }
                #endregion 

                #region key decryption
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("PublicPrivateKey.xml");
                string publicprivatekeyxml = reader.ReadToEnd();
                RSA.FromXmlString(publicprivatekeyxml);
                reader.Close();
                byte[] decryptedKey = RSA.Decrypt(getencryptedkey, false);
                pwd = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.Unicode.GetString(decryptedKey);
                byte[] dk = null;
                byte[] div = null;
                crm.getKeysFromPassword(pwd, out dk, out div);
                cryptoKey = dk;
                cryptoIV = div;
                #endregion

                string ext = Path.GetExtension(encName).ToLower();
                if (ext != ".enc")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please Enter correct File");
                    return;
                }
                string dncName = Path.GetDirectoryName(encName) + "\\" + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(encName);
                dncName = current.Date.Day.ToString() + current.Date.Month.ToString() + current.Date.Year.ToString() + current.TimeOfDay.Duration().Hours.ToString() + current.TimeOfDay.Duration().Minutes.ToString() + current.TimeOfDay.Duration().Seconds.ToString() + ".wmv";
                try
                {
                    if (crm.DecryptData(encName, dncName, cryptoKey, cryptoIV))
                    {
                        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(encName);
                        FileInfo fi2 = new FileInfo(dncName);
                        if ((fi.Attributes & FileAttributes.ReadOnly) == FileAttributes.ReadOnly)
                        { fi.Attributes &= ~FileAttributes.ReadOnly; }
                        //copy creation and modification time
                        fi2.CreationTime = fi.CreationTime;
                        fi2.LastWriteTime = fi.LastWriteTime;
                        //delete encrypted file
                        File.Delete(encName);
                        MessageBox.Show("File Decrypted");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("The file can't be decrypted - probably wrong password");
                    }
                }

                catch (CryptographicException ex)
                { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }
                catch (IOException ex)
                { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }
                catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
                { //i.e. readonly
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

To copy-protect a video file, the best way to accomplish it used to be apply DRM to it. That way you can restrict how may times it should play or how long it should be available to the user, but that still could be broken via a lot of means.

You cannot make any video 100% copy protected. Please read the article below. If that was the case, the hollywood movies wouldnt be freely available via the torrent networks.

http://www.streamingmedia.com/Articles/Editorial/Featured-Articles/DRM-Is-Dead-79353.aspx

Comment: Thanks Aby For posting, Actually Video's are provided in usb . And I to protect the video's (copy protection) from usb . I have searched on internet but not found anything. So I thought of encrypting and decrypting video . Truly saying this is a new task , I have never gone before. The part of encryption and decryption is done, but playing it is tough.  So what you say, What I have to do and steps for doing.

Comment: @user3119503, what you probably can do to stop casual users from copying will be 'hide' the videos somehow in the USB drive (maybe by setting the file attributes or by changing the file extension or as you mentioned, do some kind of encryption to it, and have another autorun exe along with the USB drive, which will rename/decrypt the file back and opens up the video via a suitable player... but this is not at all foolproof.

Comment: Same as I thought, My exe on usb will decrypt the encrypted file(.enc). it's working fine I have decrypted file to (.dnc) ., but I don't know how to play this decrypted file in player.

Comment: @user3119503 why does it decrypt to '.dnc' ? try to rename it back to .avi or .mp4 (which was your original extension) and try to play it.

Comment: Your words worked for me, by changing the format to original file format. But decrypting a file create the chance for copying file. Can we try for playing the video file from decrypted memory stream ?

Comment: @user3119503, you didnt 'changed' the format, but merely changed the extension. Yes, decrypting the file will create a chance for copying it, and thats unavoidable. You can play a video from a memory stream, but thats not that easy. see this http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/77347f21-4221-4ef0-a43f-68c77e5f7e4c/play-a-video-from-a-memory-stream?forum=csharpgeneral

Even if you play it from memory stream, users still will be able to save it via tons of ways !

Comment: Yes I changed the extension not format so silly mistake . So there is no way for copy protection? Is there any option we can secure video from memory stream?

Comment: @user3119503, yes, if you can use a Secure cryptoprocessor, instead of a usb stick. In your code sample, you are even saving the key in a file with your USB ??

Comment: I have taken decrypted data into memory stream . But doesn't find any way for playing video through memory stream . Searched on google and get hint to use DirectShow.Net . But DirectShow.Net have number of examples . I am trying to play video in Window Media Player , is there any option for playing through Memory stream .